# Pods can't communicate in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, networking, microservices, fastapi, kubernetes-pod

I have two pods. One pod (main) has an endpoint that queries other pod(other) to get the result. Both pods have services of type ClusterIP, and the main pod also has an ingress. The main pod is not able to connect to other pod to query at the given endpoint.

[image]
In the above image, `/` endpoint works, but `/other` endpoint fails.

Below are the config files:

```yaml
# main-service.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: main-service
  labels:
    name: main-service-label
spec:
  selector:
    app: main # label selector of pod, not the deployment
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 8001
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8001
```

```yaml
# other-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: other-service
  labels:
    name: other-service-label
spec:
  selector:
    app: other # label selector of pod, not the deployment
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 8002
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8002
```

[image]

All the docker images, deployment files, ingress etc are made available at: [this repo](https://github.com/harshraj22/smallProjects/tree/master/hello).

Note:

- I entered the `other` pod using `kubectl exec`, and I am able to make curl request to `main` pod, but not vice versa. Not sure what is going wrong.
- All pods, services are in default namespace.

Comment: share error you are getting and curl you are trying.

Comment: tried: `curl http://other-service:8002/` from `main` pod, error got: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to other-service port 8002: Connection refused`

Comment: while `curl http://main-service:8001/` from `other` pod, works as expected.

Comment: connectino refused check pod is up & ready plus did tried service dns getting resolved properly ?

Comment: @HarshManvar Yes, the pod is up and ready as shown in the screenshot. The DNS Resolution is: `other-service.default.svc.cluster.local has address 10.101.153.225` using command `host other-service` from `main` pod

Comment: that's weird, as you not using readiness probe pod will be ready only by default even if there is any error internally plus not sure FastAPI run on all port or have to configure to listen one port ?

Comment: I checked the logs of the pods, there no error on the pod side. I have configured fastapi to run on specific port (8001 for `main`, 8002 for `other`) and used the same ports for their deployment, service & ingress.